# sails js RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, sails.js, sails-mongo

Am getting this error from my heroku application logs. Same code on my local machine is running perfectly. But not on heroku server, Here is the exact error from the terminal.

```
    2015-02-09T12:00:03.532045+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/1/websocket/37ykGNWYvQ20k6c2LH4k?__sails_io_sdk_version=0.10.0&__sails_io_sdk_platform=browser&__sails_io_sdk_language=javascript" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=6f3206e0-db44-4252-8eba-75a6d5724be0 fwd="95.34.203.67" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=598515ms status=101 bytes=129
    2015-02-09T12:00:03.431464+00:00 app[web.1]: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    2015-02-09T12:00:03.430489+00:00 app[web.1]:         throw message;      
    2015-02-09T12:00:03.430500+00:00 app[web.1]:               ^
    2015-02-09T12:00:03.360874+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-02-09T12:00:03.430103+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:246
    2015-02-09T12:00:03.531458+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/app/issues" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=b95a2e6f-7573-4581-8523-e745c125f6c6 fwd="192.168.0.146,112.196.35.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1563ms status=503 bytes=0
```

Did some R&D and found its due to some updations  in sails version on mongoDB version. But I have not done any updation for this. Please suggest some answers how to fix this issues